# Laravel Can't get item in an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my blade.php, suppose the post user is the logged in user

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
        {{$user = App\User::find($post->user_id)}}
        {{$user}}
        {{Auth::user()}}    
@endforeach
```

Output on page:

```
{"user_id":"123","email":"123@com","password":"1234","first_name":"Tony"}
{"user_id":"123","email":"123@com","password":"1234","first_name":"Tony"}
{"user_id":"123","email":"123@com","password":"1234","first_name":"Tony"}
```

If I want to get the first_name only

I change

`{{Auth::user()}}`     to    `{{Auth::user()->first_name}}`

I can get "Tony"

but if I change
`{{$user}}`     to     `{{$user->first_name}}`

I got error

> "Trying to get property of non-object" (View: C:\PathToProject\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what the double curly brace syntax does in Laravel Blade. When it pre-processes the view, it effectively turns them into an echo statement like this:

```
// This
{{ $x }}

// Will become this
<?php echo($x); ?>
```

You can't do assignment logic like you are trying to do within those curly braces because `echo` isn't a standard function, [it is a language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) and doesn't work that way.

The recommended approach is get that value in your controller and pass it to your view. Something like:

```
return view('dashboard', [
   'user' => App\User::find($post->user_id)
]);
```

If you absolutely need to get it within the view (not recommended), you will have to fallback to plain old PHP for that:

```
<?php $user = App\User::find($post->user_id); ?>
```

And then you can access it.

**EDIT**

---

In the case of each post having a user, you should use [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) to pull the user when you get the posts. Something like:

```
$posts = Post::withUser()->get();
```

And your scope might look something like:

```
function scopeWithUser($query) 
{
    return $query->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id');
}
```

Comment: In PostController:    return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);         How can i return this   'user' => App\User::find($post->user_id)?

Comment: In that situation, you should get the user details in the query used for getting the posts. Model scopes are perfect use case for that.

Comment: hi, whether the "function scopeWithUser($query) " use in PostController? I have no idea for this query scopes

Comment: this is my table on dynamodb::::::     **users** Table: user_id | email | name | password

Comment: **posts** Table: id | body | user_id

Comment: You will have to read the documentation and maybe watch some of Jeffrey Way's videos on Laracasts to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this "hack"

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
        {{--*/ $user = App\User::find($post->user_id); /*--}}
        {{$user->first_name}}
        {{Auth::user()}}    
@endforeach
```